# htaccess RewriteRule for different files in same directory with SEO

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I have this code so far in trying to get to the file news.php in a fixed directory name. It doesn't work, because it still loads the other one below named *profile*.

```
RewriteRule ^/?FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/news.php?artist_id=$1&page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The url itself is this:

```
domain.com/FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/RANDOM_NAME/RANDOM_ID/news
eg. domain.com/guitarists/joe-bonamassa/999/news
```

where '**news**' is the actual **news.php** in: **FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME**

The one with *profile* actually works, but news.php doesn't:

```
RewriteRule ^/?FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/profile.php?artist_id=$1&page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

domain.com/FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/RANDOM_NAME/RANDOM_ID/profile
eg. domain.com/guitarists/joe-bonamassa/999/profile
```

We are fetching the content from the dBase on the RANDOM_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, found the answer after switching the two lines.
Didn't know about this structure.

```
RewriteRule ^/?FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/news/?$ /FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/news.php?id=$1&page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /FIXED_DIRECTORY_NAME/profile.php?artist_id=$1&page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

If anyone can help me making this code better, please do!